# Side-By-Side div if enough space, otherwise stack with 100% width

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, css-float

I have a container `#main-element` whose width is variable based on window size among other things. Inside this container I have some number of elements and a footer container `#wrapper` that is bottom-aligned (always `width: 100%` of the parent) and contains two divs, `#left` and `#right`.

[image: Layout]

The `#left` element is freely scalable down to `min-width: 300px` and `#right` element has a set `width: 120px`. The behaviour I'm trying to accomplish is:

- If the width of `#wrapper` is large enough to hold both elements (`>= 320px`), display its children allowing `#left` to fill the remaining width;
- If `#wrapper` cannot contain both elements, allow `#left` to take its parent entire width and display `#right` below.

I have managed to implement this... mostly. The last thing I cannot figure out is how to force `#right` to be below not above `#left` if they cannot both fit in. I'm convinced there is an easy solution that I am failing to see.

I'm preferably looking for a solution that does not require `JS` and is compatible with older browsers (e.g. `flexbox` is probably out of the question).

My code so far is included below. *Note* that the JS part is *IRRELEVANT* to the problem and included for demonstration only.

```js
!function(t){t(document).ready(function(){t.fn.asize=function(){t(this).animate({width:t(this).css(t(this).width()+"px"==t(this).css("min-width")?"max-width":"min-width")},{duration:3e3,step:function(i){t("span",this).text(Math.round(i)+"px"),t("#left").text(Math.round(t("#left").width())+"px"),t("#right").text(Math.round(t("#right").width())+"px")},complete:function(){t(this).asize()}})},t("#main-element").asize()})}(jQuery.noConflict());
```

```css
#main-element {
    /* this element HAS to be relative */
    position: relative;
    
    /* below rules are irrelevant */
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 360px;
    max-width: 570px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}

#wrapper {
    /* width is always 100% and always aligned to bottom */
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#left {
    /* force div to have at least 300px and exclude #right from its width */
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 300px;

    /* below rules are irrelevant */
    background-color: #aa0;
    height: 50px;
}

#right {
    /* show on the right; width always set, height equal to #left's height */
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    width: 120px;

    /* below rules are irrelevant */
    background-color: #990;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- main widget container -->
<div id="main-element">
    <!--some number of elements inside the widget -->
    <span></span> 
  
    <!-- footer of the widget-->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="right"></div>
        <div id="left"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the answer i posted you want?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you looking for.

I have used **`display:table`** for `wrapper` class and **`display:table-column`** for inner elements that are `left` and `right` class.

Also you **need media query** to add screen width breakpoints. Here i used width from your `main-element` class like **`@media screen and (max-width: 570px)`**. You change as you want 570px to say 360px.

So when screen reaches **at break-point** the left class div gets `min-width:100%;`, which would forcefully push `right` class div below it.

Here when `right` div goes below i had made it `float:left`, you can remove it and do as per your requirement.

This is what i understood you want. If not then comment, would try else.

[JSFiddle : DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vju8obto/)

```css
#main-element {
  /* this element HAS to be relative */
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto; /* ******** ADDED ******** */
  /* 100pxrules are irrelevant */
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 360px;
  max-width: 570px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
p {  /* ******** ADDED ******** */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#wrapper {
  /* width is always 100% and always aligned to bottom */
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: table;  /* ******** ADDED ******** */
}
#left {
  /* force div to have at least 300px and exclude #right from its width */
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 300px;
  display: table-column;   /* ******** ADDED ******** */
  /* below rules are irrelevant */
  background-color: #aa0;
  height: 50px;
}
#right {
  /* show on the right; width always set, height equal to #left's height */
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
  display: table-column;   /* ******** ADDED ******** */
  /* below rules are irrelevant */
  background-color: #990;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 570px) {   /* ******** ADDED ******** */
  #left {
    float: left;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  #right {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main-element">
  <!--some number of elements inside the widget -->
  <span></span> 
  <p>
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
    content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
    versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose
  </p>
  <!-- footer of the widget-->
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your response :) This is nearly perfect - the only issue is that screen width is not the only thing that determines my `#main-element`'s width. The widget is to be embedded in different places throughout a complex web application and depending on where it is may have different size constraints. Any way to do this without `@media` queries? Thanks :)

Comment: @BartPlatak, Afraid to say not possible without  `@media` queries if you use CSS. But if JavaScript/JQuery is not an issue, would be better than CSS solution.